# allow only specific ips to access site and allow all to access specific file

Tags: apache, file, directive

I have this configuration in my httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 66.220.144.0/20 69.63.176.0/20
</Directory>

<Files crossdomain.xml>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

What I am trying to achive is allow facebook to access the web application and deny everyone else but allow everybody to access the file crossdomain.xml. Unfortunately the above configuration is not working. The result of the above config is the crossdomain.xml file is still being blocked. Can anyone help me on this configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory:

> Directory-path is either the full path
>   to a directory, or a wild-card string
>   using Unix shell-style matching.

So your `<Directory>` tag should be using the full path to the document root folder, not the path relative to the website.